# How to use Smack API voice/video chat

Tags: java, smack

I'm trying to create an instant messenger in java using the SMACK API. My ultimate goal is to provide voice as well as video chat using a google(gmail) id. The API doesn't matter. Just something that works.

I have googled a lot, but could not find any good documentation. I found a library called libjingle, but it supports only c++.

Has anyone implemented this in java before, or have any suggestions on how to get voice and video chat to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is smackx-jingle, which is part of the standard smack distribution.

There are [test cases](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/jingle/extension/test/org/jivesoftware/smackx/jingle) you may want to take a look at to help you figure out how to use it.  Unfortunately, the author of that extension did not provide documentation for the API.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I want to know one thing , according to this http://www.francisrobichaud.com/index.php/2007/07/28/video-streaming-using-jingle-library/ there is need to have openfire server and spark client.
Does that mean openfire server should be running to voice/video chat everytime??? I want my application to do video chat overinternet only.i dont wanna run anyserver. do openfire thingy is really necessary???

Comment: Openfire is just an XMPP server, same as gtalk.  If you are going to use XMPP then you client will have to connect to an XMPP server.  This is how XMPP clients talk to each other.  Jingle data streams are typically managed by the servers, but the data is transferred directly between clients.

Answer (score 1):

smackx-jingle is obsolete and very unlikely to work. You might want to look at these instead:

https://code.google.com/p/jitsi-jingle/

https://code.google.com/p/minijingle/